# Android button setBackgroundColor change the size of the button

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I create android button programmatically, and I put this butons in a TableRow, every thing work fine, but when I change the backgroudColor the colored button not respect the size as it do without the color:

[image]

My code is:

```
val btn = Button(this)
btn.isEnabled = false
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
btn.layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(150, 150)
```

When I don't use the `setBackgroundColor` the size is correct.

I don't understand why the size is changes, is there any way to change only the default gray color of the button, without the size is changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default background for a button is not a solid color, but is rather a graphic (e.g. a [nine-patch bitmap](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)) that has paddings and margins built into it. Thus, when you replace that background image with a color, all of the built-in paddings and margins are thrown away.

Instead of setting a background color with `setBackgroundColor()` you could try using [`setBackgroundTintList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)) which should tint the existing background image with your chosen color(s).

Alternatively, you would need to manually set the margins and paddings after changing the background to the solid red color, something that is much more painful to do via code than it is in a layout XML file.

Example layout file:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Red Button"
        android:backgroundTint="#a00"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Default Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Which yields this rendering:
[image: red button and default button laid out horizontally]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I used `empty.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED))` and it gives the same result, but yes when I make a custom padding I can get an acceptable result ;)

Comment: Maybe setting a image as a background could be better no?

Comment: Yes, you could certainly create your own background nine-patch to get the margins and paddings all set along with the color and shape that you want.

Answer (score 1):

if your `app theme` is `material-theme` then there is a default paddings applied to the button. that's why the color fills the whole canvas of the button after you apply it. try to restore the padding (I believe it's 8dp for all edges).

Comment: I'm new in androind, but yes, when I use margin it gives an accepted result, but I think there are a better way to solve this

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter this line here `btn.layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(150, 150)` overrides your button layout configurations so definitely btn will loose the paddings. it's just how android works. Either you declare your button in an xml file and then you inflate it or you specify the paddings again. Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your replay, I create my Button programatticly look here `val btn = Button(this)`